# What do I need to know about using a PG database in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I'm using a SQlite3 database in development and a PostgreSQL database in production (Heroku). I'm running into some issues that may or may not be directly related to the PG database, but I'd like to know what I need to be leery of and what differences there are between the two.

For instance, are there certain things (be it syntax or anything else) that don't work with a PG database, but do with a SQlite3 one?

Does this block of errors from the log have anything to do with the PG database?

```
2012-12-30T20:27:15+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/books host=fast-journey-7822.herokuapp.com fwd=71.7.18.2 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=7ms connect=8ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-12-30T20:27:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/books" for 71.7.18.2 at 2012-12-30 20:27:15 +0000
2012-12-30T20:27:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
2012-12-30T20:27:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yXWQ/0j0AbCJ8Ytw3p7kvL0qgYFe0LTfSevhLChzk94=", "book"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"f", "queued"=>"f", "title"=>"", "author"=>""}, "commit"=>""}
2012-12-30T20:27:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

Comment: I'm afraid you need more specific diagnostics.

Comment: Okay. I just didn't know if there were common things to be aware of when working with a PG database in production.

Comment: Well, I'm not a ruby-on-rails guy, but I'd strongly suggest that you run the same database in development and in production. They are different and that may turn out to be important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the same database in all environments then this issue is irrelevant.

Comment: I realize that and am now installing PostreSQL on my machine. I had just always used SQLite so that's how the app is set up!